# Algorithm for merging graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph, merge

I am looking for an algorithm to construct a graph from two subgraphs. The problem is as following:

Given two graphs g<sub>1</sub>(V, E) and g<sub>2</sub>(V, E), find a graph G(V, E) where V(g<sub>1</sub>) ⊆ V(G), V(g<sub>2</sub>) ⊆ V(G), E(g<sub>1</sub>) ⊆ E(G) and E(g<sub>2</sub>) ⊆ E(G). I use adjacency list to store data and merge two graphs by visiting vertex/edge. However, the time complexity is higher than O(n<sup>2</sup>). Is any better algorithm?

Comment: what's the merging method?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: this question is more suited for https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I also recommend that you read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), as well as all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons your questions might become down-voted. Finally, once you written some code I really recommend that you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: thanks, i will try cstheory.stackexchange.com